# CSV and fields with spaces

Tags: perl, csv

I am using [`Text::CSV_XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS) to create CSV files. I see that if a field has a space then it is outputted within double quotes e.g.

```
john,smith,"Some address",,,,bla
```

I was wondering are the double quotes mandatory in the example? Or is it some configuration option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Subbeh has already suggested, you can set `quote_char` to undef when calling `new`, to suppress this, as per https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS#new

I'd question whether you *should*, though. In the CSV specification, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180, these quotes are always permitted and sometimes necessary (although strictly only when the field contains a separator character or a quote character itself). Since it's perfectly valid for them to be there, and any CSV-parsing tool you pass the data to later will cope ... I'd be inclined to let Text::CSV do its thing.

In particular, if you set `quote_char` to undef as suggested, fields which contain `sep_char` (comma, usually) will lead to breakage.

**Edit:** You can set `quote_space` to a false value in your call to `new` to prevent this specific behaviour (of quoting fields with spaces in), which the CSV spec neither mandates nor prohibits.

Comment: Use [`quote_space`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS#quote_space) instead of `quote_char` to handle quoting of fields containing spaces.

Comment: Oh, well spotted, I'll fold that into my answer!

Answer (score 3):

you can set  `quote_char` to change this behaviour:

> **quote_char**
>
> The character to quote fields containing blanks or binary data, by default the double quote character (`"`). A value of undef suppresses quote chars (for simple cases only). Limited to a single-byte character, usually in the range from `0x20` (space) to `0x7E` (tilde).
>
> `quote_char` can not be equal to `sep_char`.

from [https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS#new](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS#new)

Comment: Are you aware that the docs linked are from an ancient version of Perl? https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS would be a more useful link, in general.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that. The metacpan site wouldn't load here

Comment: to clarify, I'm not talking about the site, so much as the age of perl 5.8 (and the modules/docs bundled with it)

Comment: Use [`quote_space`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS#quote_space) instead of `quote_char` to handle quoting of fields containing spaces. Setting `quote_char` to `undef` will screw up fields containing the separation character.